# Java GUI set background color when run keep having grey color then display the background color

Tags: java, background-color

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;



     public class ButtonExample{
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
        f.setSize(300, 250);
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(2);


        final JTextField tf = new JTextField();
        tf.setBounds(75, 52, 150, 30);

        JButton b = new JButton("Hit it!");
        b.setBounds(50, 150, 80, 30);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tf.setText("Hello world!");
            tf.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            }
        });

        JButton c = new JButton("Colse");

        c.setBounds(170, 150, 80, 30);
        c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });
    f.add(b);
    f.add(tf);
    f.add(c);


    f.setLayout(null);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
}
```

Here basically my code is, I set the background color blue,but the first it appears grey then after few seconds it goes to blue, I was trying to figure it out while not really work, hope you guys can give me some help

Comment: 1. Don't use `null` layouts but rather the layout managers with nested JPanels. 2. The inner JPanels should be non-opaque (`.setOpaque(false)` so that the background color shows through. 3.  Call `pack()` on the JFrame after adding all components and before setting it visible

Answer (score 0):

> but the first it appears grey then after few seconds it goes to blue,

I don't see this problem. I will admit sometimes I do see a slight flicker of a few milliseconds, but that is not repeatable.

So here are my suggestions:

1. All Swing components should be created on the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)`. So you should be using `SwingUtilities.invokeLater(...)` to create you GUI.
2. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. So you should a) set the layout, b) add the components c) pack() the frame d) make the frame visible. Although you should NOT be using a null layout, for this simple example I would still use the same logical order except you would use setSize(...) instead pack() before making the frame visible.
3. Don't use magic values: `f.setDefaultCloseOperation(2);`. We don't know what "2" means. The API has variables for you to use. For example `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE`. Use these variables to make the code more readable.

Here is a slightly restructured version of your code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ButtonExample
{
    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
        f.setLayout(null);
        f.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        final JTextField tf = new JTextField();
        tf.setBounds(75, 52, 150, 30);

        JButton b = new JButton("Hit it!");
        b.setBounds(50, 150, 80, 30);
        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                tf.setText("Hello world!");
                tf.setBackground(Color.cyan);
            }
        });

        JButton c = new JButton("Colse");
        c.setBounds(170, 150, 80, 30);
        c.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        f.add(b);
        f.add(tf);
        f.add(c);

        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setSize(300, 250);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater( () -> createAndShowGUI() );
/*
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
*/
    }
}
```

Read the [Swing Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/TOC.html) for Swing basics. There are section on:

1. `Concurrency in Swing` - to explain more about the `EDT`
2. `Using Layout Managers` - for examples of using the standard layout managers

Comment: Thanks really Appreciate